# Android Mobile Browser Changing href attr to #

Tags: jquery, android, jquery-mobile

I'm having a problem with the href attr showing as '#' when using an Android Browser. In the desktop browsers I have tried (Chrome/Firefox) it alerts correctly as "http://test/dir/action/" but on Android 2.3 & 4.0 devices I have tried it comes up only as '#'.

See jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7gfm3/

Comment: I got the same results as you do, with stock browser and others too (on Android 2.2). It would seem there's a bug with jquery. But why use `delegate` instead of `$("..").click()`?

Comment: I've had trouble with click & live/on firing multiple events with JQuery mobile & ajax page linking. Delegate seems to resolve those problems at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this was fixed in the current test version of JQuery Mobile. See:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4372